# ResourceModel->delete() not deleting row in custom table

Tags: database, model, magento2.4, resource-model, repository

I am writing a module which imports additional product information into a custom table with SKU as the PK.

If there is already a row in the custom table regarding the SKU, i have to delete the old row first, otherwise an Error "Unique Constraint violation found" is thrown.

However, when i call ResourceModel->delete(), nothing seems to happen on my custom table.
I can see in the Model object regarding that SKU, that the isDeleted flag is now true and storedData is now length 0.
Then i tried ResourceModel->save(), got a new empty Model object from the Factory, add the new Data for the SKU to it and save() using ResourceModel or transaction->save(). This only prevented the error,but the row in the custom table stayed the same.

**How do I delete from my custom table in the right way?**

This is the current code with a workaround, which is not using the ResourceModel to delete:

```
$stockImportModel = $this->stockImportFactory->create();
                                                $this->stockImportResourceModel->load($stockImportModel, $sku);
                                                if(!$stockImportModel->isEmpty()) {
//                                                    Delete with Model/ResourceModel not working. Delete condition in ObjectRelationProcessor empty.
//                                                    $this->stockImportResourceModel->delete($stockImportModel);
                                                    $connection  = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
                                                    $tableName = $connection->getTableName(self::SAP_INVENTORY_TABLE);
                                                    $whereConditions = [
                                                        $connection->quoteInto('SKU = ?', $sku),
                                                    ];
                                                    $connection->delete($tableName, $whereConditions);
                                                }
                                                $stockImportModel = $this->stockImportFactory->create();
                                                $stockImportModel->addData([
```

ResourceModel:

```
 protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ResourceModelName');
    }
```

Model:

```
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('catalog_product_advanced_information', 'sku');
        $this->_isPkAutoIncrement = false;
    }
```

Comment: why do you have the product SKU as PK and not use a a regular auto_increment column?

Comment: I wanted a table with sku as pk, so that it is unique and i can get the products by sku with the model. I am a beginner so that approach might also be wrong :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Sidenote on using PKs*** - I suggest you don't use the SKU as PK. If you want the table to refer products, you can easily use the product entity_id as FK with the proper constraints for (at least) delete like 'cascade', which will ensure that when a product gets deleted, the row from your custom table also gets deleted. Plus, you can surely retrieve the product entity_id if you know its SKU.

Although the SKU is a unique value, a simple unique integer ID column will do better and you will avoid the *'Unique Constraint violation found'* error. Also Mysql works very well with integer keys so it will fetch/ update the data faster ;) You can also set the ID column to use auto_increment (in Magento this is 'identity'=true) this will guarantee keys in a sequential order, adding +1 at each new row.

***What to do now?*** I would recommend you first rewrite your custom table and use the proper PK, and FK constraints. Then, I recommend you give it a chance to understand the basic concepts of working with factories, repositories and resource models in Magento and then put them to practice. I have a hunch that if you try to do this the right way, you won't need to delete your rows when an update occurs :) .

Here are some resources which I suggest you go through and I think they might help you with this:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/factories.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html
https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories/

Comment: thanks, that is really helpful!

Comment: you are welcome, @Max, feel free to upvote or mark as solved the above answer so that other people see it too.

Comment: Sure, did both. Others can only see it when my reputation got to 15+ though.